# Does facebook url scheme works for iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, url-scheme

I would like to know about Facebook custom url scheme does work for iphone simulator? Or does it work in general and does it supported by Facebook?

I read some topics about it and some of them says it is not supported anymore and some of them have concern about it is official or not.

I cannot active my Developer device so I need to use simulator. Does it work on simulator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work on iOS Simulator **IF** there were a version of the Facebook app available that you could install on the Simulator. However, there is not. So it doesn't work.

As an aside: Do not attempt to develop iOS applications without a real iOS device that you can test them on. The iOS Simulator is not an emulator — it does not function identically to a real device. (In particular, it runs binaries compiled for x86, not ARM.) If you do not test your application on a real device before submitting it, you are likely to end up having your application rejected for bugs that you could have easily spotted and fixed yourself.

Comment: Please read my answer more carefully. The `fb://` URL scheme only works if the Facebook app is installed, **which is not possible on the simulator**.

Comment: Yes I meant devices. Sorry for inconvenience